# MariaDB 10.3.18 does not recognize any command line options

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have a CentOS 7 box on which Mariadb 10.3.18 is installed from the mariadb repo. After recent update via yum, the mysqld is no longer accepting any command line parameters:

```
# mysqld --print-defaults
mysql: unknown option '--print-defaults'
```

it happens with any other parameters except --help. Is it a bug in the latest mariadb version or am I missing something?

Comment: What does it say when you run with `--help` which works?

Comment: What does `whereis mysqld` and `type -a mysqld` say? Does the result match mysqld in your installation?

Comment: `# mysqld --help` returns as expected: mysqld  Ver 10.3.18-MariaDB for Linux on x86_64 (MariaDB Server) ... Usage: mysqld [OPTIONS]

Comment: `# type -a mysqld` mysqld is /usr/sbin/mysqld

Comment: The error (`mysql: unknown option '--print-defaults'`) is not from `mysqld` at all, it's from `mysql` client. But if `/usr/sbin/mysqld` was just symlinked to `mysql`, then `mysqld --help` would have returned help from `mysql`, not from `mysqld`. Moreover, even the `mysql` client shouldn't fail on `--print-defaults`, it's still a valid option. Try checking your original command line for invisible symbols which mess up both the executable name and the arguments. And of course check what `/usr/sbin/mysqld` really is -- unlikely as it is, it might be replaced by some misbehaving wrapper.